# Library is not registered on new project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Good morning.

I've searched over the web and Microsoft's documentantion and didn't see any matches for the same error. When I click `New Project`, on Visual Studio 2015, I receive the following error:

```
Library is not registered. (Exception from HTRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
```

There are evidences that the error may be on `.NET 4.6`, which VS 2015 requires, but reinstalling it didn't solve the problem.

[image: VS message]

I've found no matches and no way to solve it. Did anybody here deal with the same problem?

*Footnote*: It's not about removing libraries. The error happens by a simple click on `New Project`.

Comment: If you can't find a solution, but are anxious to get started, you could leverage yeoman in a short-term. `npm install -g yeoman` `npm install -g generator-aspnet` `yo aspnet`.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VS2015?

Comment: Two times. And also .NET 4.6.

Comment: It is not a .NET error.  You'll get this kind of problem if VS isn't installed correctly, usually because the machine's registry is damaged by a previous install of a trial or beta that was not correctly uninstalled.  Running the installer with the /uninstall /force command line options tends to fix the damage.